# How to distinct a field (which has several duplicates in search result) in ElasticSearch by C#?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I was trying to get/search results from an elasticsearch server. But i have only get permissions so i cannot put some mapping index into ES server or change any configurations in ElasticSarch.

> .../testindex/doc/_search?q=country_code:99&size=5000&pretty

```
{
    "took": 58,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 0.2876821,
        "hits": [ // Above result numbers may not be correct!
            {
                "_index": "testindex",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "George",
                    "lastname": "Bush",
                    "owner_code": "555"
                    "country_code": "99"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "testindex",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "John",
                    "lastname": "Smith",
                    "owner_code": "444"
                    "country_code": "99"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "testindex",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.28582606,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Mike",
                    "lastname": "Brown",
                    "owner_code": "555"
                    "country_code": "99"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- I tried create new indices but i already failed because i don't have any permissions about that.
- I also tried below code:

```
[JsonObject]
class CustomDTO
{
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("lastname")]
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("owner_code")]
        public string owner_code { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("country_code")]
        public string country_code { get; set; }
}
// ElasticSearch v6.x
var result = _client.Search<CustomDTO>(s => s
    .Index("testindex")
    .Type("doc")
    .From(0)
    .Size(5000)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("my_terms_agg", t => t
            .Field("owner_code.keyword")
            .Size(2000)
        )
    )
    .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs
         .Field(f => f.country_code)
         .Query("99"))));
```

Expected result is: /* After distinct "owner_code". */

```
{ 
   { 
      "name":"Mike",
      "lastname":"Brown",
      "owner_code":"555",
      "country_code":"99"
   },
   { 
      "name":"John",
      "lastname":"Smith",
      "owner_code":"555",
      "country_code":"99"
   }
}
```

And it returns no bucket or documents (Count: [0]).

Pseude SQL code that i need in ElasticSearch too.

> select * distinct "owner_code" from testindex where country_code = "99"

So i should get these result (Mike-Brown-555-99, John-Smith-444-99 if check above.). And ignore other results which has same "owner_code".It doesn't matter name and/or lastname fields are different. I want to distinct "owner_code" field and search for "countryCode" field. It is very easy to do in SQL Query but i am very confused in ElasticSearch (v6.x).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share information from `result.DebugInformation` and which version of elasticsearch and NEST do you use?

Comment: Can you share the mapping to? . Also share the  CustomDTO c# class (pretty sure your class didnot match with the es mappings).